# If $|X|\leq 1$ a.s, then there exists $Y$ taking values $\pm1$ s.t $E[Y|X]=X$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is a question from Klenke's book in the chapter on Martingales. As in the title suppose that $X$ is a random variable with $|X|\leq 1$ almost surely. Show that there is a random variable $Y$ taking the values $\pm1$ such that $E[Y|X]=X$. Some observations that I have are that we can not have $X$ and $Y$ independent, since then $E[Y|X]=E[Y]$, and we can not have $Y$ be $\sigma(X)$ measurable, since then $E[Y|X]=Y$. This sort of puts the brakes on my initial idea which was to construct $Y$ as either a simple function or limit of simple functions involving inverse images.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: You want to have $\mathbb P(Y=+1\mid X=x) =g(x)$ and $\mathbb P(Y=-1\mid X=x) =1-g(x)$ for the suitable $g(x)$ which has $\mathbb E[Y \mid X=x] =x$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$.  It is not difficult to find since $g(x)-(1-g(x))=x$

Comment: So from what I have calculated, it seems that $Y$ should take the value $+1$ with probability $E[\frac{X+1}{2}]$ and the value $-1$ with probability $E[\frac{1-X}{2}]$. However, I am confused about how to show that a random variable defined in this way will give me what I want. How do I know that I can pick such a measurable $Y$ where $\sigma(X)$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(X) :={X+1\over 2}$. Given $X$, toss a coin with Heads probability $p(X)$ and Tails probability $1-p(X)$. Let $Y=+1$ if the coin shows Heads, $Y=-1$ if it shows Tails.